# Definitions of positive and negative rational numbers

Tags: analysis, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, rational-numbers

In https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Rational_number a rational number is defined as an equivalence class of pairs in the usual manner, and a rational number $r$ is called *positive* (*negative*) if it contains a rational fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ with $a$ and $b$ of the same sign (of different signs).

In [https://www.math.wustl.edu/~freiwald/310rationals.pdf](https://www.math.wustl.edu/%7Efreiwald/310rationals.pdf) instead a nonzero rational number $\frac{a}{b}$ is called *positive* if it is possible to write $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$, where $c,d \in \mathbb{N}$, and $\frac{a}{b}$ is called *negative* if it is possible to write $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$, where exactly either $c \in \mathbb{N}$ or $d \in \mathbb{N}$ and not both.

Do the different notions of negative and positive rational numbers defined above coincide?

Comment: Yes they coincide. Try to prove that, it isn't difficult.

Comment: Since $0$ is rational but neither positive nor negative, both definitions might need extending

Comment: Presumably, "are both of the same sign" means both $a$ and $b$ of the form $-m$ (for $m \in \mathbb{Z}$), preceded by $-$ or both are of the form $+ m$?

Comment: Every $a,b$ are of the form $-m$ for $m \in \Bbb Z$, because $\Bbb Z$ contains the additive inverses of all its numbers. $a, b$ are of the same sign if they are both $0$, or if they are both $\ne 0$ and either (both $a, b \in \Bbb N$) or (both $-a, -b\in \Bbb N$.